# Powershell issues to Automate Login to website

Tags: powershell, authentication, automation

I am new with powershell scripts. I currently have this written to open a website and input the username and password. I got it to enter the desired value but when I submit the login it reads the values as blank. Any advice is appreciated.

```
    $ie = New-Object -ComObject 'internetexplorer.Application'
    $ie.Visible= $true

    $username="123456"

    $password="F12345"

    $ie.Navigate("https://ppar.com/sso/mmsi")

    While ($ie.Busy -eq $true) {Start-Sleep -Seconds 5;}

    $form = $ie.document.forms[0]
    $inputs = $form.GetElementsByTagName("input")
    ($inputs | where {$_.Name -eq "username"}).Value = $username
    ($inputs | where {$_.Name -eq "password"}).Value = $password
```

[Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Qg5F.jpg)

[Example of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Qg5F.jpg)

Comment: Some sites block some or all automation efforts, by design, regardless of what you may try to use. They actively code their site against such efforts. Just as some prevent other functions like printing, etc. I've not bee to the site you are showing, but I'd not be surprised if they were blocking/restricting stuff.

Comment: It appears this site is restricting automation, as even with Invoke-* it errors off with stuff like...  [Exception             : System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.] [ErrorDetails          : Server Error
                        405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.
                        The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access.]